# Import CSV and group by name and then first instance of datetime

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, rdp

I am trying to get RDP session event( event ID: 22 and 25) for a number of computers and export as a CSV file. I need to get the first instance of a RDP session the user has initiated on each day( There may be many RDP session reconnection/day) so I can create a report what time each user is initiating the first RDP session.

```
$week = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 10)
$Events = Get-WinEvent  -ComputerName $ComputerName -LogName $LogName | Where-Object { ($_.TimeCreated -ge $week) -and (($_.Id -eq '22') -or ($_.Id -eq '25')) }  
  
foreach ($Event in $Events) {
    $EventXml = [xml]$Event.ToXML()
    $EventTime = $Event.TimeCreated.ToString()
    $Username = $EventXml.Event.UserData.EventXML.User
}
```

The CSV file has the time column which contains the connection time in (mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm) format. I am struggling to get the group and sort command to get the first instance of a connection in each day.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output? How do you want to group the output? Is it like, the first Event ID per User per Date?

Comment: Hi Santiago.. i need to group by Username then date and then first instance time for that date. So i know each day what time the initial RDP connection was initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added lots of comments to help you with the thought process

```
$logFilter=@{
    LogName='Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational'
    ID=22,25
    StartTime=[datetime]::Now.Adddays(-30)
}

# Get all events 22 & 25 for the past 30 days
$events=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $logFilter

# Since we want the first Event per Date, we need to 
# group all events by each Day
$groupByDay=$Events|Group-Object {$_.TimeCreated.ToShortDateString()}

# Looks like this
PS /> $groupByDay

Count Name                      Group                                                                                                       
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                       
   68 5/4/2021                  {System.Diagnostics.Even...
   76 5/3/2021                  {System.Diagnostics.Even...
   12 5/2/2021                  {System.Diagnostics.Even...
   22 5/1/2021                  {System.Diagnostics.Even...
   62 4/30/2021                 {System.Diagnostics.Even...
   46 4/29/2021                 {System.Diagnostics.Even...

# Now we want to group each day by User and get the first log for each one of them
# To see an example of how it looks you can use this =>
$groupByDay[0].Group|Group-Object {$_.Properties.Value[0]}

# Note
$events[0].Properties.Value[0]
# Is the same as
([xml]$events[0].ToXml()).Event.UserData.EventXML.User

# Create a new export grid
$grid=[collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::new()

# For each day in all days logs
foreach($group in $groupByDay)
{
    $groupByUsers=$group.Group|Group-Object {$_.Properties.Value[0]}

    foreach($user in $groupByUsers)
    {
        # Logs are always sorted by newest to oldest
        # we can assume that the first log we get from pipeline
        # is the one we want for each user
        $temp=$user.group|Select -First 1

        # Add this object to our export grid
        $grid.Add(
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Time=$temp.TimeCreated.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')
                EventID=$temp.Id
                User=$user.Name
        })
    }
}
```

Export should look something like this:

| Time | EventID | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/04/2021 16:00 | 25 | user.example1 |
| 05/04/2021 15:55 | 25 | user.example2 |
| 05/04/2021 14:40 | 22 | user.example3 |
| 05/03/2021 16:00 | 25 | user.example1 |
| 05/03/2021 15:55 | 25 | user.example2 |
| 05/03/2021 14:40 | 22 | user.example3 |

Comment: $Events = Get-WinEvent  -ComputerName $ComputerName -LogName $LogName | Where-Object { ($_.TimeCreated -ge $week) -and (($_.Id -eq '22') -or ($_.Id -eq '25') -or   ($_.Id -eq '24') -or  ($_.Id -eq '40')  ) } .. Why do i get error when i add more event id

Comment: @Enigma glad it helped you, so for the error, I'm not sure, but why not use the same `FilterHashtable` method I'm using on the script? It's faster than using `where-object`. Also you can do  `-and ($_.Id -match '^22$|^25$|^24$|^40$')`